# Open HTML page modal based on value of PHP $_GET

Tags: javascript, php, html, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal window on page (page is e.g. menu.php), and when I click a button, i go to

```
window.open('menu.php?data=click','_self');
```

(I'm actually opening other page, that does something in PHP and returns to menu.php with header('Location: menu.php?data=click'), but for sake of simplicity I wrote it like this).

Now, is there possibility to get that value and say something like

```
if ($_GET['data'] == click)
   //open menu.php but with modal windows
```

**In other words, can I be able to open php page with modal if $_GET parameter has certain value?**

Comment: PHP couldn't care less what produced an http request. just because you're doing an `window.open` doesn't make whatever arrives at the server magically different. it'll be an http request, it'll have a query parameter, and it'll be IDENTICAL to what would have been sent if you manually put `example.com/menu.php?data=click` into your browser's address bar.

Comment: That being said, PHP cannot open a new window/tab in the browser. That can only be done with client-side code, e.g. a `<a target="..." ...>` or JS code.

Comment: I don't understand, header('Location: ...') is in PHP and it can perfectly open whatever page i want it to.

Comment: yes, but that can only affect the tab/window where the request came FROM. if you want the script's response to go into a different window/tab, then PHP can't help you with that. in real world terms, PHP will deliver a pizza to a house that already exists. it will not build a new house and then deliver the pizza.

Comment: I don't want it to go to different window/tab. Maybe I explained it badly. I just want to check if data parameter has some value and draw modal if it does.

Comment: php also can't open modals. it can only output some JS code that eventually executes on the client to cause a modal to be opened.

Comment: I know it can't but I set 'data' in PHP. Everything is on client side here. So, you think JS can open it if 'data' is set? I thought only HTML can open it

Answer (score 0):

One simple way that can be done is by setting a cookie when the page is opened

```
setcookie("menuClicked", true);
```

So after, you can check by

```
if isset($_COOKIE["menuClicked"]){ ...
```

Then you can either unset the cookie or set as false!